# How is it possible that a +2 question gets deleted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169003/is-it-necessary-to-add-a-constructor-all-the-time-in-child-class) question on SO.

Now I see that it got deleted - but the upvote count for the question shows +2. How is it possible that non-moderators would see the "delete" link ... that only shows up when the question shows -3 or more?

And beyond that: I think I read more than once that "question is a duplicate" doesn't translate to "question should be deleted". So isn't "positive reception" of question with answers an indication to **not** delete it?

Comment: This is a real problem in SO. Good contents is lost due to users who are too eager to (ab)use their power. Worth posting a discussion on MSO about this to see how to handle it, e.g. moderator warnings to those eager users.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd So you suggest to add another question on meta SO ... to ask about "should the question have been deleted"?

Comment: @GhostCat no. No point asking about each specific question, I'm sure there are hundreds like this. I suggest starting a discussion like "Should we delete duplicates with positive score?" and bring some examples, e.g. that question you mention here. My opinion is "No we should not" but I'm only a single person, so worth seeing what others think. And like I said, if the consensus is to not delete, find ways to make those who act against it to stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Every* closed question can be deleted, but you need to wait at least 2 days after the closure. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for [trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) when a post scores -3 or lower.

The last sentence is probably what you were thinking about.

The article also warns about deleting duplicates:

> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; [they can serve as a signpost](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/), directing users to useful answers on another question.

Yes, this is clearly a duplicate and it should've been closed instead of answered. I'm not contesting that *at all*. But it shouldn't have been deleted (so I voted to undelete). For example, searching for "child class constructor" won't find the duplicate target but it will find the question you linked to. While "child class" is not the correct term for this, it's understandable that people will search for something like this. I don't care about "positive reception", all I care about is this (from the [blog page about duplicates](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/20/linking-duplicate-questions/)):

> There's often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people **tend to ask and search using completely different words**, and the better our coverage, the better odds our fellow programmers can find the answer they're looking for.

Comment: Yup, also voted to undelete.

Comment: We are getting to many duplicates in some areas and some user probably should put in more effort find the duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: I'm not contesting the closure *at all*, I'm just stating that this is a potentially valuable signpost.

Comment: not so sure, even with exact title in google I find resources on google that points to answer on SO, while signposts are good, scattering answers is a problem. The best solution would be if user took 1 min to first find duplicate and then post answer on the duplicate, but true this dream will never come through.

Comment: @PetterFriberg probably (though I can't prove it) because the two questions are now linked. I agree fully with the rest of your statements.

Answer (score 5):

> I think I read more than once that "question is a duplicate" doesn't translate to "question should be deleted". So isn't "positive reception" of question with answers an indication to not delete it?

No, positive reception doesn't mean deletion is out of order.

If a question is yet another duplicate of a beaten track it is much more valuable to either add a better answer to an existing Q/A then to add yet another take on the same topic. That only scatters knowledge, bringing down the information density on that specific issue. You're doing a disservice to future visitors by answering that and so do the users who un-deleted that question.

Comment: and yet, if the future visitor finds the original before the duplicate he will never know of the disservice... but if he finds the dupe before the original then probably you should search your problem somewhere else.